# Why are the images missing in newsletter emails created using Simplenews?

Tags: 7, emails

I have created newsletter using the [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module. I have inserted images using the WYSIWYG editor. The mail received is missing those images. There is no indication of images in the newsletter. How to make the images appears in the newsletter email?

mailsystem: SMTP

Answer (score 1):

For Sending newsletter with image you have to send mail in HTML format not in text format. One more thing for Html mail format you have to use [Mimemail](https://drupal.org/project/mimemail) or [Html mail](https://drupal.org/project/htmlmail).

Mail content images have absolute src path. So that image will be accessible by email.